# Excel Macro to show applied formulas as Text

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I want to loop through all columns and check the row 2 which has the data to check if there are any columns with references to other cells or if there are any formulas in them. So, if there is no reference to any other cells or if it is empty or it just has data then show the heading of that column, otherwise show the referenced column or that formula being used. The output of this macro when run needs to be shown at the bottom as the last row of the data. For the below example I am not getting the last column to show "Price * Units" on my outputs. Some of the columns could have other complex formulas with some "If statements" and concatenations so I need to cater for this as well.

[image: 1]

Please see below some of the code I have started with but I need some help achieving the above:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ApplyFormulas()
    Dim lastColumn As Integer
    Dim headerRow As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim headers() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim headerName As String
    Dim cell As Range

    ' Set the starting row for data and header
    headerRow = 1

    ' Find the last column with data in row 1
    lastColumn = Cells(headerRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    ' Find the last row with data in column 1
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Store headers in memory
    headers = Range(Cells(headerRow, 1), Cells(headerRow, lastColumn)).Value

    ' Copy headers to the last row
    Rows(lastRow + 1).Value = Rows(headerRow).Value

    ' Loop through each column and display headers or formula in terms of headers in the last row
    For i = 1 To lastColumn
        If i + 1 < lastColumn Then
            Set cell = Cells(2, i)
            If IsDataColumn(cell, lastRow) Then
                ' If it's a data column, show the header
                headerName = headers(1, i)
                Cells(lastRow + 1, i).Value = headerName
            ElseIf IsFormulaColumn(cell) Then
                ' If it's a formula column, show the formula in terms of headers
                Cells(lastRow + 1, i).Value = GetFormulaInTermsOfHeaders(cell.formula, headers)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Debugging messages
    MsgBox "ApplyFormulas completed."
End Sub

Function IsDataColumn(cell As Range, lastRow As Integer) As Boolean
    ' Checks if the column contains only data
    IsDataColumn = cell.HasFormula = False And cell.formula = "" And cell.Value <> "" And cell.Row = lastRow
End Function
Function IsFormulaColumn(cell As Range) As Boolean
    ' Checks if the column contains a formula
    If cell.HasFormula Then
        IsFormulaColumn = True
    ElseIf InStr(1, cell.formula, "=") > 0 Then
        IsFormulaColumn = True
    Else
        IsFormulaColumn = False
    End If
End Function

Function GetFormulaInTermsOfHeaders(formula As String, headers As Variant) As String
    ' Returns the formula in terms of column headers
    Dim pos As Integer
    Dim refStr As String
    Dim headerName As String

    pos = InStr(formula, "[")
    
    Do While pos > 0
        refStr = Mid(formula, pos + 1, InStr(pos, formula, "]") - pos - 1)
        headerName = GetHeaderFromReference(refStr, headers)
        formula = Replace(formula, refStr, headerName)
        pos = InStr(pos + 1, formula, "[")
    Loop

    GetFormulaInTermsOfHeaders = formula
End Function

Function GetHeaderFromReference(reference As String, headers As Variant) As String
    ' Returns the header name from a reference
    Dim refColumn As Integer
    Dim headerName As String

    refColumn = Range(reference).Column
    headerName = headers(1, refColumn)

    GetHeaderFromReference = headerName
End Function
```

I have tried to search for various threads on this platform but am finding it hard to find the solution to my problem and I have tried to write above but not getting it right:

Step 1: Check for the heading row in row 1 and keep in memory
Step 2: Start looping through all the cells in row 2 to check if there is a reference to another column or if there is any sort of excel formular or anything other then data or if it is empty.
Step 3: If there is just data then the output must show the heading of its column
Step 4: If the column data for example references another column then it must show this referenced column heading and NOT the current heading column.
Step 5: If there is a formular that calculates something then all the referenced columns in this formular must be shown as a test output. So for example `=A2*B2/C2` , output must show `Units*Price/Avg` as text etc.

Comment: If you convert your data to a ListObject and use structured references then that's going to make your task much easier.